# Pass multiple parameter from angularjs to asp mvc controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass multiple parameter from angularjs to asp mvc controller using viewmodel, but its not working. For reference please look into the image of the html page.
[image: Html page]

I want to pass OrderId and array of Id and Rating.

Here is the html code :

[image: Html Code]

Here is my angularjs controller and factory code :

[image: Angular Code]

Here are the two viewmodel classes :

[image: viewmodel classes]

[image: viewmodel classes]

Here is the mvc controller :

[image]

As you can see I am not able to get OrderDetails from the viewmodel. So how to get it?

Comment: When you debug in the browser, what's in `d` when making that AJAX call?

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework? if so, is "OrderDetails" coming from a different table? I believe you need to use `include(x => x.OrderDetails)` for it to bring it up due to Eager Loading...

Comment: well I can see the following : new:  { 
OrderId: test
ProductRating:  { 
0: 2
1: 4
2: 3
 } 
 }@david

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. While push just Identify duplicate data.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.company = [{id:1, name:"Sole Trader", rating:4},{id:2, name:"Pvt Ltd", rating:3},{id:3, name:"LLC", rating:5}];
$scope.Newrat = [];  
  $scope.addRatingbyId = function(pushdata){
  if($scope.Newrat.length != 0){
  angular.forEach($scope.Newrat, function(value, index){
  if(value.id == pushdata.id){
   $scope.Newrat[index].rating = pushdata.rating;
  }else{
   $scope.Newrat.push(pushdata);
   }
  });
 }else{
 $scope.Newrat.push(pushdata);
 }
  }
  $scope.sendRating= function(){
  //send $scope.Newrat  
  console.log($scope.Newrat);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCtrl" >
{{company}}
<table><tr><th>id</th><th>Name</th><th>Rating</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="com in company">
<td>{{com.id}}</td>
<td>{{com.name}}</td>
<td>
<input type="text" ng-model="com.rating" ng-change="addRatingbyId(com)">
</td>
</tr></table>
<input type="submit" ng-click="sendRating()">
{{Newrat}}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, now I am able to get the com.id, but still I am not able to send multiple $scope data to the factory and receive it in the mvc controller. I want to do something like this $scope.click = function () {
        testfac.submit($scope.Company, $scope.Newrat).then(function (d) {
            //do something
        })
    }; fac.submit = function (d) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Test/Submit',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ t: $scope.Company, o: $scope.Newrat }),
            
        });
    };
    return fac

Comment: Do it controller itself.  like this $scope.click = function () {var data  = JSON.stringify({ t: $scope.Company, o: $scope.Newrat }); testfac.submit(data).then(function (d) { //do something }) }; fac.submit = function (getData) { return $http({ url: '/Test/Submit', method: 'POST', data: getData)};

Answer (score 0):

Well I found it.

```
$scope.click = function () { // button click function
        var data = {
            OrderId: $scope.new.OrderId,
            OrderDetails: $scope.Company
        }
        testfac.submit(data).then(function (d) { //factory calling
            console.log(d)
        })
    };
```

We have to merger the different $scope in a variable (var data) and pass it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I fill some options of http:

```
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "Test/Submit",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { Data : $scope.data },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.YourDatamodel = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.errorReturn = response.statusText;
});
```